# Using if/else on a json parsing to display markers on a map android

Tags: json, google-maps, if-statement, google-maps-markers

I have 2 json files, the first one is for categories and the second is to generate markers and put them in the map.

The first screen of my app show the categories on a listview, and when i click one of the categories it should display the markers according to the category selected on the map, I have no problem displaying the map or reading json

Example json categories:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": "01",
      "categoria": "Restaurante"
    }
  ]
}
```

Example json places:

```
{
  "places": [
    {
      "id": "01",
      "lat": "20.583566571214778",
      "long": "-100.37047419121245",
      "dist": "100m",
      "star": "1",
      "icon": "03",
      "name": "Restaurante San Pedro",
      "cat": "Restaurante",
      "sched": "9:00 - 23:00",
      "text": "Una gran seleccion de platillos para su deleite."
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem, is that it won’t display the markers, I am using an if to compare that the category selected is the same of any category business in places json, and if it’s the same it display the marker, I use a toast to see the result and 
It’s the same, I don’t know why it won’t execute the if sentence instead of else

```
if (cat == recuperamos_variable_cat) {
  LatLng lugares = new LatLng(dlatitud, dlongitud);
  Marker ubicacion2 = mapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lugares).title(name).snippet(text));
  Toast mensaje2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cat + recuperamos_variable_cat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
  mensaje2.show();
} else {
  Toast mensaje2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No hay coincidencias", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
  mensaje2.show();
}
```

I put the rest of the code:

```
//recover the value of the category selected
final String recuperamos_variable_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("TAG_ID");
final String recuperamos_variable_cat = getIntent().getStringExtra("TAG_CAT");
// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ();
// Creating JSON Parser instance
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
// getting JSON string from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
try {
  // Getting Array of Contacts
  places = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PLACES);
  // looping through All Contacts
  for (int i = 0; i < places.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = places.getJSONObject(i);
    // Storing each json item in variable
    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
    String lat = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
    String lon = c.getString(TAG_LONG);
    String dist = c.getString(TAG_DIST);
    String star = c.getString(TAG_STAR);
    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
    String cat = c.getString(TAG_CAT);
    String icon = c.getString(TAG_ICON);
    String sched = c.getString(TAG_SCHED);
    String text = c.getString(TAG_TEXT);
    double dlatitud = Double.parseDouble(lat); //Convertimos valores a double
    double dlongitud = Double.parseDouble(lon);
    if (cat == recuperamos_variable_cat) {
      LatLng lugares = new LatLng(dlatitud, dlongitud);
      Marker ubicacion2 = mapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lugares).title(name).snippet(text));
      Toast mensaje2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cat + recuperamos_variable_cat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      mensaje2.show();
    } else {
      Toast mensaje2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No hay coincidencias", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      mensaje2.show();
    }
  }
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: you are comparing the two strings with == which only tells you if the two string variables are pointing to the same object. For comparing the content of strings use the equals method - cat.equals(recuperamos_variable_cat)

Answer (score 0):

Alredy could do that

Have to use this

if (cat.equals(recuperamos_variable_cat)) {

instead of

if (cat == recuperamos_variable_cat) {

Hope this helps someone in the future